# How to grant select on v$session to a common user see all session of all pdbs?

Tags: oracle

I've done it':

```
grant select on sys.gv_$session to c##dba_foo container = all;
```

But I can't see sessions from pdbs.

Also, the c##dba_foo need permission to kill others session of all pdbs. Do I need something else? I only grant alter system.

```
GRANT ALTER SYSTEM TO c##dba_sonda container = all;
```

Note: This user cannot connect to pdb to kill the sessions. Need be from cdb root.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
alter user c##dba_foo set container_data=all for sys.v_$pdbs container = current;
alter user c##dba_foo set container_data=all for sys.gv_$session container = current;
alter user c##dba_foo set container_data=all for sys.V_$SESSION container = current;
```

and

```
GRANT ALTER SYSTEM TO c##dba_foo container=all;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's easier, look:

```
C:\>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Oct 26 16:47:54 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys/aaaaa@xeraiz as sysdba
Connected.


SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 XEPDB1                         READ WRITE NO


SQL> grant select on v_$session to teideusr;
grant select on v_$session to teideusr
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01917: user or role 'TEIDEUSR' does not exist


SQL> select username from dba_users where username = 'TEIDEUSR';

no rows selected
```

We did not find this Schema because it is in another container.
We are going to change to the container where it is.
(We are still SYS)

```
SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT


SQL> alter session set container=xepdb1;

Session altered.


SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
XEPDB1


SQL> select username from dba_users where username = 'TEIDEUSR';

USERNAME
------------------------------
TEIDEUSR

SQL> grant select on v_$session to teideusr;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now you can use the v$session table inside a PLSQL procedure.
;) olé